# Problema com filtro via JSON

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite,

Estou aqui com um problema com filtro via json para distritos e concelhos passo a explicar.

O user escolhe um distrito e ele filtra e lista noutra selectbox os concelhos que estão associados aquele distrito e o sistema está a funcionar o único problema e que esta nos concelhos aparecer varias opções como NULL.

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.carregando').hide();
    $('#distritos').change(function(){
        if( $(this).val() ) {
            $('#cod_cidades').hide();
            $('.carregando').show();
            $.getJSON('ajax/processa_concelhos.php?search=',{distritos: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                var options = '<option value=""></option>'; 
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="'+j[i].id_concelho+'">' +j[i].titulo+'</option>';
                }   
                $('#concelhos').html(options).show();
                $('.carregando').hide();
            });
        } else {
            $('#concelhos').html('<option value="">– Escolha um Concelho –</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

Select distritos

```
<select name="distritos" id="distritos">
<option value="0">-- Escolha um Distrito --</option>
<?php
$sql = "select * from distritos order by titulo";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.utf8_encode($row['titulo']).'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Select concelhos

```
<select name="concelhos" id="concelhos">
 <option value="">-- Escolha um estado --</option>
</select>
```

Processa_concelhos.php

```
<?php
require_once("../gtm/bd/funcoes.php");
ligarBd();  

$distritos =  $_REQUEST['distritos'] ;

$concelhos = array();

$sql = "select * from concelhos where id_mae='".$distritos."' order by titulo";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
$concelhos[] = array(
    'id_concelho'   => $row['id'],
    'titulo'        => $row['titulo'],
);
}
echo( json_encode( $concelhos ) );
?>
```

Comment: Poe o código da consulta que retorno o json.

Comment: Está todo ai direitinho

Comment: Bem tive a ver e já descobri o que estava causando o retorno de valores NULL era por causa dos acentos no codigo de retorno json adicionei ao titulo utf8_encode e ficou a funcionar direitinho

Comment: @CésarSousa publique uma resposta com a resolução. Sua solução pode ser usada por uma pessoa com o mesmo (ou parecido) problema futuramente.

Comment: Claro que sim irei fazer isso estava mesmo a pensar fazer isso mas fiquei na duvida se era permitido responder a própria pergunta

Comment: @CésarSousa Não há problemas nisso, como pode ver [nesse link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Inclusive esse assunto já foi [discutido no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37).

Comment: Não sabia obrigado por se disponibilizar a ajudar e por esse conhecimento assim já fico a saber obrigado

Answer (score 3):

O problema que estava a ter retorno de valores NULL era devido a acentuação de alguns concelhos, pelo que a solução passou por usar utf8_encode ao retornar os valores para ele ler os acentos.

Codigo corrigido com a solução

```
<?php
require_once("../gtm/bd/funcoes.php");
ligarBd();  

$distritos =  $_REQUEST['distritos'] ;

$concelhos = array();

$sql = "select * from concelhos where id_mae='".$distritos."' order by titulo";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
$concelhos[] = array(
'id_concelho'   => $row['id'],
'titulo'        => utf8_encode($row['titulo']), //linha corrigida
);
}
echo( json_encode( $concelhos ) );
?>
```